# SSDBGrid not populating with data

Tags: vb6, recordset

I'm running a select query to populate a recordset, which I am them setting to be the datasource of a grid.

Relevant code:

```
Dim dbLedger As Database

Set DB_Session = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

Set dbLedger = DB_Session.OpenDatabase(DB_Period_Name$)

Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [Account_Code] , [Name] FROM [Ledger] ORDER BY [Account_Code] Asc"

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = dbLedger.OpenRecordset(SQL)

grdExport.DataSource = rs
```

However, the grid doesn't display the rows at all. The query is working as `rs.recordcount` returns 1574.

Am I doing something wrong? I've not set any properties on the grid and this the only code in the form class so far so it isn't being cancelled out by anything.

Screenshot of the form follows:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `Set` to your last line of code.

Comment: Some grids require a `.Refresh` or a `.Rebind` to be performed.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Nope, still the same result

Comment: @BillHileman Still the same after those

Comment: Which grid control, exactly, is it?  FlexGrid?  dbGrid?  ListView?  Hard to tell from just a screenshot.

Comment: Have you verified your recordset contains data?

Comment: @BillHileman it's in SSDBGrid

Comment: I'm not at my home PC where I have VB 6 installed, so I can't delve into specifics until later today, but perhaps someone else here can pick it up from here in the mean time.  It may be one or more of your properties of the grid control are not set properly, but without access I can't be any more help for now.

Comment: As @BrianMStafford suggested, test your result set for null.

Comment: @BillHileman `MsgBox(rs.recordcount)` returns 1574

Comment: @BrianMStafford No worries, whenever you're able to look into it is fine, thank you. I'll keep looking into the properties but I don't recall setting any.

Comment: I have no SSDBGrid on my system.  Who makes it and what is the OCX filename?

Comment: @BillHileman It's a Sheridan grid, I believe Infragistics may own it now

Comment: Have you used this control before successfully?  Is the correct  data mode property selected?  Is there a reason you prefer this grid over other grids?